# What is the C# equivalent of Java/Scala's ConfigFactory?

Tags: java, c#, scala

I have a Scala file I need to convert to C#. The file uses `import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}` and loads configurations with `ConfigFactory.load()`. What is C#'s closest equivalent to this?

Does C#'s `System.Configuration;` work the same way, is `IConfigurationFactory` found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041387/Design-Patterns-Abstract-Factory) better, or is there something else that makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typesafe/Lightbend Config has been ported to .NET at https://github.com/akkadotnet/HOCON would be the most direct equivalent.

Comment: How can I add that to my existing project?